# GCC Compile error when copying compiled version to another host

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ubuntu, compilation

I compiled gcc on one of my ubuntu 10.10 hosts, and installed it in /c. I can compile c and c++ programs fine on that host but when i copy /c (which contains bin, libexec etc) to a ubuntu 10.04.2 host i get:

```
/c/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when compiling a simple .c file.

I've also installed and compiled gmp, mpfr and mpc from source (same versions as i did on the 10.10 host) but it's still coming up with the same error.

The reason i'm not recompiling gcc on each host is because it takes too long, and prefer not to use the gcc (from the build-essential) deb that comes with ubuntu

Please help

Comment: Are the system specs exactly the same? It is important to note that pre-compiled binaries may not work with different architectures (i.e. x86, x86_64, etc.) - also, I am not aware of the differences in Ubuntu versions, but this could also pose a problem. Your best bet is to recompile on your second machine if you want to make sure it is working optimally.

Comment: @RageD both of the hosts are the same arch: uname -m
i686

Answer (score 8, accepted):

did you export your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable? Looking at the error, it's not able to find libmpc.so.2.

Try 'locate libmpc.so.2' and if you can find that, 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=

Comment: Is it possible to compile gcc as static? so it doens't rely on a gmp, mpfr, mpc after compiled?

Comment: @rjoshi exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH worked! thanks. but regarding my last question "Is it possible to compile gcc as static? so it doens't rely on a gmp, mpfr, mpc after compiled?" is it possible?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, you can compile static by passing full library path. when you compile, give path as  -L/usr/local/lib/libgmp.a

Comment: apt-get already says that libmpc-dev is installed, but calling 'locate libmpc.so.2' returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some details on how to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Ubuntu:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location%20related%20variables